# IF I'm given the probability of a team winning a tournament, how do I calculate the probability of them making the finals?

Tags: statistics

If I know the probability of a team winning a tournament, how do I get the probability of them making the finals?

Comment: This is unclear.  What are the rules that govern who makes the finals?

Answer (score 0):

The probability of that team winning the tournament is the product of the probability of making the finals and the probability of winning the finals.  If you know the probability of winning the finals you can calculate what you want.

Comment: The probability of them winning the finals is unknown, I think youre correct in that though, I most likely need one more known variable